# ResetBinding in C#

Tags: c#

I have a function

```
public DataSet Select(string sql)
{
    //Get data source from database to DataSet
}
```

in class DataDriverExample
and in form_load, I bind to the datagridview.

```
public BindingSource bs = new BindingSource()
public void form_load()
{
    DataSource ds = DataDriverExample.Select("Select * from XYZ");
    bs.DataSource = ds;
    dataGridView.DataSoure = bs;
    dataGridView.DataMember = "TableResult";
    txtAbc.Bindings.Add("text",bs,"TableResult.Col1");
}
```

it worked, 
but I have Button Add (which adds a new record to the database)

```
public void btnAdd_click()
{
    DataDriverExample.Insert("Insert into XYZ values (\"Test\",\"Hello\",\"Bla\")");
    DataSource ds = DataDriverExample.Select("Select * from XYZ");
    bs.DataSource = ds;
    bs.ResetBinding(true);
}
```

In my database it now has new record, but I get the error `Cannot bind to the property or column on the DataSource`
Sorry for my english not good.
Anyone can help me.
Tks

Comment: Haven't you forgot the `bs.DataMember = "TableResult";`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220392/cannot-bind-to-the-property-or-column-name-on-the-datasource-parameter-name-da

Answer (score 1):

To Clean up your code, create another method for your binding something like:

```
 private void LoadData()
{
    bs.ResetBinding(true);
    txtAbc.DataBindings.Clear()
    DataSource ds = DataDriverExample.Select("Select * from XYZ");
    bs.DataSource = ds;
    dataGridView.DataSoure = bs;
    dataGridView.DataMember = "TableResult";
    txtAbc.Bindings.Add("text",bs,"TableResult.Col1");
 }
```

Then just call LoadData(); on your formload and add method

```
    public BindingSource bs = new BindingSource()
   public void form_load()
   {
   LoadData();
   }
```

Add:

```
public void btnAdd_click()
{
    DataDriverExample.Insert("Insert into XYZ values (\"Test\",\"Hello\",\"Bla\")");
    LoadData();
}
```

Hope this helps

Regards

Comment: Tks your help, but i want using ResetBinding

Comment: Yes, this code work, but you should clear binding before add `txtAbc.DataBindings.Clear()`