# How to clear a binding source?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have this model:

```
public class CustomerType
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

Then, I have a binding source on a WinForms form, and its bound to existing object by doing:

```
var customerType = repository.Get(id);
bindingSource.DataSource = customerType;
```

I want to clear the datasource so I do:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = null;
```

But I get the following exception: `Cannot bind to the property or column Name on the DataSource.`

Setting the variable `customerType` to null doesn't clear the datasource.

So what is the correct way to clear the datasource?

Comment: isn't there a `bindingSource.Clear()`?

Comment: BindingSource implements IList so yes there is a bindingSource.CLear()

Comment: The datasource is just one POCO object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(CustomerType);
```

This is what visual studio assigns by default.

Comment: This does clear the bindingsource's datasource. But if I set the variable `customerType` to null, the datasource isn't cleared. Should it be cleared?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono: i don't understand, does it work or not? I don't know why the `BindingSource` refuses to work if you assign `null`. I guess because you are using a custom type as source. The error message is rather clear. The BindingSource is looking for a `Name` property, `null` doesn't have this property, it belongs to the type `CustomerType`.

Comment: I have found this related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220392/cannot-bind-to-the-property-or-column-name-on-the-datasource-parameter-name-da

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, null the data source:

```
this.bindingSource.DataSource = null;
```

Then clear the rows:

```
this.bindingSource.Rows.Clear();
```

Then set the data source to the new list:

```
this.bindingSource.DataSource = this.GetNewValues();
```

Comment: As he mentioned setting `DataSource` to null throws an exception